# Django DRF - Patch request object in viewset?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, view, request, patch

We are using oauth2 and perform force_login() in our tests simulate authentication.   However in our modelviewset, we now want to override create() to check for some specific authorization (in the requests object eg request.auth['MYROLES']) permissions we would get in our access tokens.   I cannot work out how I can patch the request object to have the expected attribute to ensure our test can work without failing due to missing object attributes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the -1.

The negativity drove me to work it out.  For anyone elses benefit:

Used drf apirequestfactory() with force_authenticate().  The trick being:

force_authenticate(request, user=user, token= {'Roles' : ['role1','role2']})

Where the dict can be expanded to include any other key value pairs your token provider implements.